# iOS Crittercism - net data collection disabled

Tags: ios, crittercism

I am using crittercism in ios project and am seeing the below logs upon launch :

```
2014-09-17 08:28:08.323 TestApp[68927:1793926] Crittercism successfully initialized.
2014-09-17 08:28:08.692 TestApp[68927:1793926] Crittercism - net data collection disabled
```

It says : NET data collection **Disabled**.

I am not getting any stats on crittercism website.
Any idea how to enable them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**net data collection disabled** is actually describing the service monitoring component of Crittercism. This is a message hit when service monitoring is disabled. This message may show up if no net data is possible to collect, due to network calls not being made or you're using an unsupported network API.

If you use the latest version of the Crittercism library, NSURLSession and Async/Sync NSURLConnection support was added. If no data is getting sent (app loads, crash reports, handled exceptions) then something is likely blocking the Crittercism API or you're using an invalid App ID. Make sure to whitelist https://api.crittercism.com.